# Deleting permission in google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

[image]

I want to remove a file from shared with me by deleting its permission.
But I can't delete it because of insufficient permissions. How can I delete it?

*What I had done so far:*

Got the metadata for the file and also its **permissionId**

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",

 "id": "1pPGyU9XvliI4U8910uehkuQ-vuuRXEVD",

 "name": "Die Hard (1988) 1080p BDRip Org DD 5.1 [Hindi + English] x264 ESubs.mkv",

 "mimeType": "video/x-matroska",

 "starred": false,

 "trashed": false,

 "explicitlyTrashed": false,

 "spaces": [
  "drive"
 ],

 "version": "135",

 "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1pPGyU9XvliI4U8910uehkuQ-vuuRXEVD&export=download",

 "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pPGyU9XvliI4U8910uehkuQ-vuuRXEVD/view?usp=drivesdk",

 "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/video/x-matroska",

 "hasThumbnail": true,

 "thumbnailLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/iVzSamm0mJK92lc16EW4TsFy8GZhcbKwUIzIwaGPtT9p2HV9bQl5SogR_nzb1zcihi5BZQ3qey0=s220",

 "thumbnailVersion": "1",

 "viewedByMe": true,

 "viewedByMeTime": "2019-06-26T17:00:11.924Z",

 "createdTime": "2018-05-16T09:54:34.010Z",

 "modifiedTime": "2018-05-16T10:24:01.186Z",

 "modifiedByMe": false,

 "sharedWithMeTime": "2018-10-21T17:22:57.170Z",

 "owners": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",

   "displayName": "free ac",

   "me": false,

     "permissionId": "00202688946253680238",

   "emailAddress": "freeac331@gmail.com"
  }
 ],

 "lastModifyingUser": {

  "kind": "drive#user",

  "displayName": "free ac",

  "me": false,

  "permissionId": "00202688946253680238",

  "emailAddress": "freeac331@gmail.com"

 },
 "shared": true,

 "ownedByMe": false,

 "capabilities": {

  "canAddChildren": false,

  "canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission": false,

  "canChangeViewersCanCopyContent": false,

  "canComment": false,

  "canCopy": true,

  "canDelete": false,

  "canDownload": true,

  "canEdit": false,

  "canListChildren": false,

  "canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive": false,

  "canMoveItemOutOfDrive": false,

  "canReadRevisions": false,

  "canRemoveChildren": false,

  "canRename": false,

  "canShare": false,

  "canTrash": false,

  "canUntrash": false
 },
 "viewersCanCopyContent": true,

 "copyRequiresWriterPermission": false,

 "writersCanShare": true,

 "originalFilename": "Die Hard (1988) 1080p BDRip Org DD 5.1 [Hindi + English] x264 ESubs.mkv",

 "fullFileExtension": "mkv",

 "fileExtension": "mkv",

 "md5Checksum": "7fdc6768744557159d790037c808c99c",

 "size": "2565619212",
 "quotaBytesUsed": "0",

 "headRevisionId": "0B8kwukeDiZGLUHpUN0xXTllYRnRBbFZYMzNsbjFUK01jZ2tVPQ",

 "videoMediaMetadata": {
  "width": 1920,
  "height": 800,
  "durationMillis": "7929080"
 },
 "isAppAuthorized": false
}
```

And I tried to delete the permission

*fileId: 1pPGyU9XvliI4U8910uehkuQ-vuuRXEVD*

*permissionId: 00202688946253680238*

```
{
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
 }
}
```

But can't remove the file from shared with me.

**EDIT 1:**

I am testing this with [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/delete#try-it)

**EDIT 2:**

I am trying to do [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TcfaGOxYSt8&t=3m30s) but with the google drive api

Comment: @DaImTo I tried to delete the permission as you suggested but it is not getting removed

Comment: Can you provide your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I am currently testing with this site https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/delete#try-it

Comment: Thank you for replying. You don't use a script. You test it using "Try this API". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes. And later use it with python

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the file is publicly shared as ``anyoneWithLink`` and shared with your email, even if the permission of your permission ID is deleted, ``sharedWithMeTime`` is not removed. Of course, when the shared file is manually deleted with your Drive, ``sharedWithMeTime`` is removed. On the other hand, if the file is not publicly shared and shared with you, when your permission is deleted, ``sharedWithMeTime`` is removed and the file is gone from your Drive. Although this situation might be the specification, I cannot still resolve this issue. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Tanaike I added edit to the question check that please

Comment: Thank you for replying. But unfortunately, I couldn't understand about it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an `insufficientFilePermissions` error because only the owner of the file can edit them. As you can see:

```
"ownedByMe": false,
```

<s>Currently there is no way to remove the files from Shared Files via API, so the options are to ask the owner to stop sharing the file with you or to delete it via the Drive GUI.</s>

**EDIT:**

It can be done, following these steps:

1. Get the ID of the file with `Drive.list`
2. Get the permissionID using the fileID by `permissions.list`
3. You will get two items with two PermissionIDs, copy the one from the item with the "shared with" email, not the *owner* email.
4. Delete the permission with `permissions.delete` using the fileID and
   the PermissionID from step 3.

Comment: Hi @Evonb, I corrected my answer. Sorry for any inconvenience.